# MySQL Trigger - Finding column names dynamically

Tags: mysql, triggers

When a table row is updated , I am getting the changed row as `NEW` object.
I need to get all column from this `NEW` row.
Is there a way to get all the column from `NEW` object, or I should manually access all the columns like `NEW.id, NEW.name`.
If a new column is introduced into the table for which I am writing the trigger, I need to manually come and add this column in my trigger.
Kindly please suggest me any ways to dynamically access all the columns from the row.

Comment: Yes, add them manually into your trigger.

Comment: @juergend , Thanks for the reply. Is there no other alternate for dynamically finding the column names

Comment: Usually programmers have their hands touch the keyboards on occasion. Goes with the job. The answer to your question, if automated, would turn every query into some real ugly code. And you wouldn't want it anyway.